# ¿Cómo puedo cargar datos desde un txt a un árbol en Java?

Tags: java, árboles-binarios

Necesito leer un archivo de texto plano txt ubicado, por ejemplo, en el disco `C:/` y guardarlo en un árbol binario, el archivo es una lista como esta:

```
172677855
542889989
137149328
331795804
```

cada string debe ser guardada en un nodo del árbol.

Comment: Y que has probado? Hasta donde has llegado? Te ha dado algún fallo? Edita tu pregunta y añade lo que has hecho hasta ahora indicando, si falla, donde falla. Lee [tour] y [ask] para ver como funciona el sitio y como hacer tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El arbol binario de java se llama [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Esta solucion solo funciona en java 10. Para que funcione en otras versiones solo hay que cambiar var por el tipo de variable que toca.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class arbol {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Path archivo = Paths.get("C:/ruta...");

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(archivo)){
        var map = lines.collect(toMap(String::hashCode, e -> e));
        var arbol = new TreeMap<>(map);//este es el arbol binario
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```